# Lenovo repository for ubuntu 22.04

Tags: updates, lenovo, repository

I upgraded my lenovo thinkstation P920 from 20.04LTS to 22.04LTS.  When I update, I get messages like

W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'sutton.bachman/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'sutton.bachman' (component misspelt in sources.list?)

I don't know what is in these repositories or if there is an equivalent one for 22.04 jammy. How would I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

That one contains Lenovo specific drivers. That repository holds [Jammy](http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com/dists/jammy/) and if you click the link there is a component "sutton". Change your repository to that and update again. See "software sources". You can alter it.

Comment: I already had the following in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.bachman-bale-meta.list
deb http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com/ jammy sutton
deb http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com/ jammy sutton.bachman
I commented out the second and the warning goes away.  There exists 
http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com/dists/focal/sutton.bachman/
http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com/dists/focal/sutton/
http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com/dists/jammy/sutton/
but not 
http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com/dists/jammy/sutton.bachman/
Is it OK that there is no jammy equivalent to sutton.bachman?