# Skipping acquire of configured file for not having the component "sutton.newell"

Tags: apt, updates, 64-bit, do-release-upgrade

I recently updated Jammy from Focal on my Thinkpad X13 Gen 1 (AMD). After the `do-release-upgrade` command, I kept receiving the following `Skipping acquire of configured file` errors:

```
$ sudo apt update; sudo apt upgrade

--snip--
Reading state information... Done
19 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'sutton.newell/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'sutton.newell' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'sutton.newell/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'sutton.newell' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'sutton.newell/i18n/Translation-en_US' as repository 'http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'sutton.newell' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'sutton.newell/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'sutton.newell' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'sutton.newell/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'sutton.newell' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'sutton.newell/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'sutton.newell' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'sutton.newell/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'sutton.newell' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'sutton.newell/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar' as repository 'http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'sutton.newell' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'sutton.newell/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'sutton.newell' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
```

I wonder what may cause these warnings.

[Update: Sept 15, 2022]

I compared the content list between `focal/` and `jammy/` on http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com/dists/. It turns out that Lenovo removed the driver named `sutton.newell` for the Jammy Jellyfish release. I have no idea why Lenovo removed them, but I'll just turn the existing lines in `/etc/apt/source.list.d/` into comments for now.

Comment: Look for the string `sutton.newell` in `/etc/apt/sources.list` or any of the files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

Comment: And do what after you find the string? Delete any lines that have sutton.newell?

Comment: similar: https://askubuntu.com/q/1426833